# SElinux integrety check

Tags: selinux

How can I check (with SELinux) access to the file by process name?

For example, we have 2 processes:

- `/usr/bin/foo1`
- `/usr/bin/foo2`

They are run under account with username `userA` and try to open for modify file:

- `/home/userA/test.txt`

I want that if `foo1` tries to open file - it's ok. But if `foo2` tries to open
this file - I have message about this in `/var/log`.

Problem is that both processes have the same user ID. And I can't use RBAC by username.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to give both `foo1` and `foo2` custom domain types to run in using SELinux policy. This would entail:

1. Create types for the binaries (e.g. `foo1_exec_t` and `foo2_exec_t`)
2. Create types for the processes (e.g. `foo1_t` and `foo2_t`)
3. Specify that when the user type (likely `unconfined_t`) executes `foo1_exec_t`, it transitions to `foo1_t` and similar for `foo2`

Then you need to create a custom type for `test.txt` (e.g. `test_t`)

Once you've done this, you can write whatever policy you like for these (including an `auditallow` rule for the particular access you're looking for). The catch is that by creating custom types, you'll have to specify all access for them.

If you're not looking to do any access control, but rather just log when something happens, the audit subsystem is a better choice, though I don't know that you can be this granular with it.